# <command line>:2:10: Macro name missing

Tags: xcode4.6, ios6.1

The project runs in Simulator and on the device,
but when I try to archive it, I get pointless error messages:

```
<command line>:2:10: Macro name missing 
<command line>:3:9: Macro names must be identifiers
```

[image]

P.S. I would like to add more details, however I completly don't understand what can be a reason for that.

Comment: do you have a line anywhere in your code that says "`#import <built-in>`" or "`#include <built-in>`" ?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No I don't. I checked whole project.

Comment: I also have no idea what is <command line>

Comment: do you have any "Run Script" build phases?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I see that error raises up on "Archiving Pods" stage. So, maybe one of the pods has some conflict.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I checked my macro and found error.

I added earlier `RELEASE = 1` to release macros, but because I used spaces(as I do in code),
it became 3 different macroses: `RELEASE`, `=`, `1`.

So I just fix that and error gone.